# Simulation and validation with pscl hurdle

Tags: r, simulation, goodness-of-fit, pscl

I am fitting a hurdle model using `pscl`'s `hurdle` function. I have not been able to tackle the following issues related to the object returned by `hurdle`:

Is there a straightforward way to simulate using the object produced by `hurdle`?

Is there a straightforward way to get the goodness of fit, such as pseudo R2?

Thank you.